# Componentwise Convergence for sequences in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that a sequence in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ converges, if and only if it converges componentwise, using $N- \epsilon$ definition.

Let $(x_{k})$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ that converges to $a$.  I have to show that for all $j = 1, 2,..,k$ $$x_{k,j} \rightarrow a_{j} \ \ \text{as} \ \ k \rightarrow \infty$$

We know,

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 : \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : \forall k > N: \lVert x_{k} - a \rVert < \epsilon$$

which means $\lVert (x_{k,1} - a_{1}, x_{k,2} - a_{2},...,x_{k,n} - a_{n}) \rVert < \epsilon$

Fix $1 \leq j \leq n$ I have to prove $\lVert x_{k,j} - a_{j} \rVert < \epsilon$

How do I continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

**1.** $$|x_{k,i}-a_i|\leq\Vert x_k - a\Vert$$

**2.** $$\Vert x_k - a \Vert \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |x_{k,i}-a_i|$$
You can figure out which of the two you need for which case. I hope this helps.

---

**Edit** (explanation)

**1.** For two vectors $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ we have: $$|x_i -y_i |=\sqrt[]{(x_i-y_i)^2}\leq \sqrt[]{(x_1-y_1)^2+...+(x_n-y_n)^2}=\Vert x-y\Vert$$

**2.** For two vectors $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ we have: 
\begin{align}
\Vert x-y\Vert &= \Vert (x_1-y_1,...,x_n-y_n)\Vert\\
&= \Vert  (x_1-y_1,0,...,0) +  (0,x_2-y_2,0,...,0)+...+ (0,0,...,0,x_n-y_n)\Vert \\
&\leq \Vert  (x_1-y_1,0,...,0)\Vert + \Vert (0,x_2-y_2,0,...,0)\Vert+...+ \Vert(0,0,...,0,x_n-y_n)\Vert\\
&= |x_1-y_1| + |x_2-y_2| + ... |x_n-y_n|\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|
\end{align}
To arrive the inequality we have used the triangle inequality. You see that those are properties for any vectors $x$ and $y$ so this applies to your sequence too.

Comment: Thank you, it's what I needed. Could you please show how these inequalities are driven? I just started this topic and I always get confused with absloute value and Norm.

Comment: Also, in my question, it should be $|x_{k,j} - a_{j}|< \epsilon$ instead of $\lVert x_{k,j} - a_{j} \rVert$, because the components are numbers and Norm applies to vectors. Correct?

Comment: @yarafoudah I added an explanation from where the inequalities came from. I have two inequalities that help you to prove your statement. You need to prove an "if and only if" statement. The one you need for one inclusion and the other one for the other. I leave it up to you  to figure out which one you need for which case.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You are using $l_2$-norm, but what if the norm is not this one?

Comment: @U2647 in finite dimensional spaces all nroms are equivalent so we can use that. If you have a specific norm then you can try to find bounds as I have done above.

Comment: @Shashi Could you please explain how equivalence allows you to generalise the inequality to other norms in real vector spaces?

Comment: @Marios Gretsas Could you please explain how equivalence allows you to generalise this to other norms in real vector spaces? –

Comment: @Dis-integrating what you mean? You mean $(\mathbb R^n, \|\cdot\|_p)$? Since the norms there are all equivalent, sequences converge iff they converge wrt to the euclidean norm. As simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

HINT

$$|x_k^{(j)}-a_j|=\sqrt{(x_k^{(j)}-a_j)^2} \leq \sqrt{(x_k^{(1)}-a_1)^2+...+(x_k^{(j)}-a_j)^2+...+(x_k^{(n)}-a_n)^2}$$ $$=||x_n-a||_2 \to 0$$ where $x_k=(x_k^{(1)},...,x_k^{(n)})$ and $a=(a_1,a_2....a_n)$

$||.||_2$ is the Euclideian norm in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Every other norm in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is equivalent to this norm,  because in a finite dimensional space,all nomrs are equivalent.